# Android Softkeyboard Pressing backbutton on new activity dismisses soft keyboard too

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am using Android Google API 10 and testing on real device running Gingerbred. From SoftKeyboard service (from sample), I am calling a help dialogue on pressing a key using:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

It displays fine. But when a user presses backbutton to dismiss the "About" activity, even the SoftKeyboard vanishes (if nothing is already in composing view e.g. in message, it comes back at New Message).

Note:I could disable backkey on About.class by using onBackPressed(), but that's not what I want. The backkey could not be disabled in SoftKeyboard class similarly, but that's not anyway what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas.

I had a similar problem and fixed it by inserting this:

```
public void showKbd(View view) {
    if(!(mgr==null)) mgr.showSoftInput(page, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

where mgr is:

```
public InputMethodManager mgr;
```

In another similar case, I put this in the manifest for the activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

This attribute forces keyboard display. Hope one of these helps...